# Add TYPO3 palette to all elements?

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-9.x

I have made a custom palette in `tt_content.php` and want to add it to all content elements on the appearance tab like this:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addToAllTCAtypes(
    'tt_content',
    '--palette--;My Palette;my_palette',
    '',
    'before:sectionIndex'
);
```

This works for everything except Grid Elements (gridelements_pi1). How do I make the new palette show up on Grid Elements as well?

Comment: Please also post the order of extensions in your `PackageStates.php`.

Comment: @MathiasBrodala `gridelements` is listed after my site package in `PackageStates.php` even though grid was installed first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comment from @MathiasBrodala lead me to finding the answer is in the order of extensions.

In this case I needed to add `gridelements` under `suggests` in my `ext_emconf.php` which ensures it will be loaded before my site package.

```
$EM_CONF[$_EXTKEY] = [
     'title' => 'My Package',
     'description' => 'TYPO3 Sitepackage',
     'category' => 'templates',
     'version' => '1.0.0',
     'state' => 'stable',
     'constraints' => [
            'depends' => [
                'typo3' => '8.7.0-9.5.99',
                'fluid_styled_content' => '8.7.0-9.5.99'
            ],
            'suggests' => [
                'gridelements' => '9.3.0-0.0.0',
            ],
            'conflicts' => [
            ],
     ],
     'uploadfolder' => 0,
     'createDirs' => '',
     'clearCacheOnLoad' => 1
];
```